# Standalone JTA 1.2 and Hibernate: JPA not rolling back?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, entitymanager, jta, weld

I'm using the "JBoss quickstart" tutorial described [here](https://github.com/jbosstm/quickstart/tree/master/jta-and-hibernate).
It demonstrates the use of distributed transactions including JPA in standalone applications.

I've downloaded the code, runs fine, all test cases are green.

It contains the following test case:

```
  @Test
  public void testJpa() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity("test1")));
    System.out.println(testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity("test2")));
    System.out.println(testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity("test3")));
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(3, testEntityRepository.findAll().size());
  }
```

I wanted to make this more interesting, by starting a transaction and rolling it back before the assert, like this:

```
  @Test
  public void testJpa() throws Exception {
    transactionManager.begin();
    System.out.println(testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity("test1")));
    System.out.println(testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity("test2")));
    System.out.println(testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity("test3")));
    transactionManager.rollback();
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(0, testEntityRepository.findAll().size());
  }
```

With the `rollback()` I would expect the `findAll().size()` to return `0`. However it continues to return `3`. Is there something I'm missing? The ability to roll back the JPA state would seem to be one of the main goals of the tutorial?

The original code for `TestEntityRepository`:

```
public class TestEntityRepository {

    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public List<TestEntity> findAll() {
        assert entityManager != null;
        return (List<TestEntity>) this.entityManager.createQuery("select te from TestEntity te").getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Long save(TestEntity testEntity) {
        assert entityManager != null;
        if (testEntity.isTransient()) {
            entityManager.persist(testEntity);
            entityManager.flush();
        } else {
            entityManager.merge(testEntity);
            entityManager.flush();
        }
        return testEntity.getId();
    }
}
```

Other code can be found [here](https://github.com/jbosstm/quickstart/tree/master/jta-and-hibernate).

Comment: Is there any specific reason to flush after persist and merge?

Comment: Please, try this: move testEntityRepository.save calls to a method inside TestEntityRepository and call it from testJpa.

Comment: @Jaumzera thanks for your suggestion. Tried as you suggested, but same effect. I guess the JPA transaction is somehow not correctly linked to the JTA transaction. Strangely enough if I replace `@Transactional` by `@Transactional(TxType.MANDATORY)` and leave out the `entityManager.begin()` in the testcase, then I get an exception saying a transaction is required, which is correct.

Comment: @Jaumzera the `flush()` is something I picked up reading other documents in search of a solution - don't remember where or why. Took it out again to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the quickstart. I've raised an issue to fix it: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBTM-2668.